# How to decide a State for Deep Q Learning for Production Line scheduling

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning, optimization, dqn

There is a production floor with W workstations and N jobs with M operations( different processing times per operation ). A job is completed only if its M Operations are completed. Objective is to reduce Idle time amongst Workstations

I am trying to use Deep Q Learning to solve this to come up with an optimized schedule but Need inputs on what you feel would the right State for RL in this case, please.

Thanks

Comment: As stated, it appears we could just sort Jobs by total duration, and schedule them in descending order. There must be other aspects of the task that you want to share above. Maybe a given Workstation can only do a certain subset of Operations? Are completion times constant? Maybe there's a cost when a Station switches among Jobs? Or a setup cost when it switches Operation types? Or a transportation cost to move materials between Stations? Also, has your Reinforcement Learner seen good + bad schedules in the training data? What heuristic rules has it picked up on so far?

Comment: Yes , there are a few qualifications we need to take care off - like certain workstations can work with certain operations

Comment: Processing times are different for the operations and currently transportation time is not considered . I am looking for a State for my reinforcement learning and I think you mean the regular constraint programming when you say sorting the jobs and calculating . 
Any idea how the state should look like ?